# Robot framework installation issue for wxPython

Tags: wxpython, robotframework

I am trying to install robot framework but getting an error for wxPython version. When I type ride.py in cmd then an error message is shown:

> "C:\Users\snar13>ride.py
>   Wrong wxPython version.
>   You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Unicode support to run RIDE.
>   wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpytho
>   n/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/"

I have done following steps:

- Installed python version 2.7, set an environment variable and verified in cmd by typing “python –version” with output “Python 2.7.12”.
- Installed Robot framework with PIP command i.e. “pip install robotframework” and verified in cmd by typing “pybot --version” with output “Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.12 on win32)”
- Installed Selenium2Library with PIP command i.e. “pip install robotframework-selenium2library”
- Installed Selenium library with PIP command pip install –U selenium.
- Installed wxPython 3.0.2.0 for Python 2.7
- Installed Robot Framework IDE – RIDE with PIP command i.e. “pip install robotframework-ride”
- When I try to open RIDE framework by typing “ride.py” in cmd it throws an error i.e. *“C:\Users\snar13>ride.py
  Wrong wxPython version.
  You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Unicode support to run RIDE.
  wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpytho
  n/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/"*
  I tried and run multiple versions of wxPython but same error is shown:
  wxPython version:
- wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py26
- wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27
- wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27
- wxPython3.0-win64-3.0.2.0-py27
  System Details:
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit

Answer (score 4):

The wxPython 2.8.12.1 architecture must match the Python installation. Looks like you need to install the 32bit version, probably wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install wxPython 32 bit Installation (make sure you should install the wxPython version same as the python version i.e. Python 2.7)