# How to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE

Tags: macos, wxpython, robotframework

Not able to run ride.py on Mac. I have tried all possible solutions provided on the website but it still says

> Wrong wxPython version. You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with
>   unicode support to run RIDE. wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/

Comment: Did you install it yet ? and what the message erorr you got after install ?

Comment: In case you were unaware, you don't need RIDE in order to work with robot framework. There are plenty of other options.

Comment: Yes i am aware but in my office they are using ride only.

Comment: @SidaraKEO yes i have installed ride. It is asking for wxPython2.8.12.1 but when i install wxPython with brew install wxPython it installs 4.0 version

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950578/robot-framework-installation-issue-for-wxpython) help?

Comment: @TAJINDERSINGH  i think you could try Pycharm IDE instead of RIDE. for me  it's better than RIDE   https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac

Comment: If you want to use wxPython 4, you can try to install RIDE from my fork, with "sudo -H pip install --pre -U https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/archive/v1.7.1.zip" (see https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/releases the Wiki has known new bugs). If you must use wxPython 2.8.12.1, it is difficult to install but it should be possible.

Comment: @Helio what will be the command to run it on mac as the one you have stated is not working and its zip folder

Comment: After the installation(and if it did not create a desktop shortcut to a shell script), you can enter the command: python -m robotide.__init__