# How do I run ride on mac?

Tags: wxpython, robotframework

I am using mac (Mojave).
I tried to run ride on my mac but failed.
I installed wxPython and then installed robotframework, robotframework-appiumlibrary, robotframework-ride with pip.

In python, Importing wx is possible but when I try to run ride.py, I get error message below.

wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robot framework installation issue for wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950578/robot-framework-installation-issue-for-wxpython)

Comment: Although the problem is similar, it is not a duplicate. The referenced question is about installing on Windows, and it was easily solved. When installing on MacOS, there are different problems.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have the wrong version of wxPython installed. Ride currently only supports old versions of wxPython (i.e. 2.8.12), which is really old. You must install that version from SourceForge.

I don't know if that version will install correctly on Mojave or not. You may need to download the source for it and build it yourself.

Comment: yes, but when I tried to install that file, the error message was popped up.

Comment: It said that It can install software because it cannot find the software to install..

Comment: Unfortunately I have not installed that old of a version of wxPython on my Mac, so I don't know how to do that. You could ask for assistance on the wxPython Google group though

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to install wxPython on MacOS, and you see it working on Python, but RIDE 1.5.2.1 (official version), does not run, then like Mike Driscoll said, it is not wxPython version 2.8.12.1. There are some problems on installing that version on MacOs (starting with security block, and a wrong error message).

If you really want to install RIDE, I have a newer version in my fork of the original project. The page is at https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE.

Since you have already a wxPython installed, you can install development RIDE directly from the source code (or from the [releases](https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/releases) page).

```
sudo -H pip install -U https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/archive/release.zip
```